# Static variable inheritance in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, syntax, static, blender

I'm writing Python scripts for Blender for a project, but I'm pretty new to the language. Something I am confused about is the usage of static variables. Here is the piece of code I am currently working on:

```
class panelToggle(bpy.types.Operator):
    active = False

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self.active = not self.active
        return{'FINISHED'}

class OBJECT_OT_openConstraintPanel(panelToggle):
    bl_label = "openConstraintPanel"
    bl_idname = "openConstraintPanel"
```

The idea is that the second class should inherit the *active* variable and the *invoke* method from the first, so that calling OBJECT_OT_openConstraintPanel.invoke() changes OBJECT_OT_openConstraintPanel.active. Using *self* as I did above won't work however, and neither does using *panelToggle* instead. Any idea of how I go about this?

Comment: Okay, it seems I can use self.__class__.active or type(self).active to let the method inherit properly. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using static variables in the first place?  That doesn't seem sensible.  Is this `active` attribute some kind of global, shared among all `PanelToggle` instances?  If so, why isn't it actually global?  Or why isn't in some more global shared object?

Comment: I want each panelToggle subclass to have its own "active" variable that can be accessed without creating an instance. If I understand the use of the "global" keyword correctly, I'd have to insert a 'global active' line first in 'invoke(..)' before just using active like a local variable.
Doing this gives an error saying the global name 'active' is not defined.
I'm not sure I understand what's wrong with my approach, however.

Comment: Why class-level?  Clearly you want each subclass to have a variable.  Why is it at the class level?  That's what makes little sense.  Why isn't this an ordinary instance variable?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

use `type(self)` for access to class attributes

```
>>> class A(object):
 var  = 2
 def write(self):
   print(type(self).var)
>>> class B(A):
 pass
>>> B().write()
2
>>> B.var = 3
>>> B().write()
3
>>> A().write()
2
```

**UPDATE**

for a `classmethod` is event easier, and most natural

```
class A(object):
     var  = 2
     @classmethod
     def write(cls):
       print(cls.var)
```

and a `staticmethod` should not depend on the instance type, so such form of dispatch is possible here

Comment: is `type(self)` in any way different from using `self.__class__`?

Comment: It is not at the moment. But some features can be implemented later. Also you can do some monkey patch to type function.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.8.5 and I noticed a difference: I could not modify type(self).var from inside an instance method of the class. I had to use self.__class__.var in order to be able to modify it within an instance method. Not sure why?

Comment: is there a way to accomplish this if `write` were a static method?

Comment: @ekkis updated an answer a little bit

Answer (score 4):

You can access `active` through the class it belongs to:

```
if panelToggle.active:
    # do something
```

If you want to access the *class* variable from a method, you could write:

```
def am_i_active(self):
    """ This method will access the right *class* variable by
        looking at its own class type first.
    """
    if self.__class__.active:
        print 'Yes, sir!'
    else:
        print 'Nope.'
```

A working example can be found here: http://gist.github.com/522619

---

The `self` variable (named `self` by convention) is the current instance of the class, implicitly passed but explicitely recieved.

```
class A(object):

    answer = 42

    def add(self, a, b):
        """ ``self`` is received explicitely. """
        return A.answer + a + b

a = A()

print a.add(1, 2) # ``The instance -- ``a`` -- is passed implicitely.``
# => 45

print a.answer 
# => print 42
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to be able to do the same with OBJECT_OT_openConstraintPanel. I want it to have its own static "active" variable, inherited from panelToggle. I also want to make the "invoke" method work in the subclass (access its own "active" variable instead of its parent's)

Comment: Edited my post and added sample code in http://gist.github.com/522619, hope it helps.