# Setting Parent Class Attributes with Super

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can you set parent class attributes using `super()` in python 2.7? I would expect the following code to work, but it does not:

```
class A(object):
    val_a = 1

class B(A):
    val_b = 2

    def set_a(self, val):
        super(B,self).__class__.val_a = val

b = B()

b.set_a(3)
```

It gives the following error:

```
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'super'
```

Is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: you should go for `thisclass` instead of `class`. `super().__class__` is the class attrribute of super object, while `super().__thisclass__` is the class attribute of the parent class.

Comment: @Faibbus, I just replaced `__class__` with `__thisclass__` and it worked. Thanks! I wonder why this is the case?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this though? B inherits from A, any instance of B has access to the attributes of A. You should be setting the value on `self.__class__.A.`

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I want to set the value for the class A and any other classes that may inherit from A, rather than just for class B. I don't think the code you included would do that.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475488/static-variable-inheritance-in-python

Comment: See the post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475488/static-variable-inheritance-in-python

Comment: @Faibbus: That's `B`, not `A`. It looks like the questioner wanted `A`.

Comment: @user2357112: `super(A, self).__thisclass__.val_a` would change A's attribute, wouldn't it ?

Comment: @Faibbus: It would, but `super(A, self).__thisclass__` is a really convoluted way to write `A`, with no benefits.

Comment: I have edited the title and content of the question to make the intent more clear. Thanks for all the advice.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you set static class attributes using `super()` in python 2.7?

No.

> I would expect the following code to work, but it does not

First, `__class__` actually gets special-cased by `super`, to return the `super` instance's class, rather than performing the MRO search `super` usually does.

Second, there's no `B.__dict__['__class__']` entry for `super` to bypass, so even if `__class__` wasn't special-cased, it'd still be `B` instead of `A`.

Third, if you want to refer specifically to class `A`, rather than whatever happens to come next in `self`'s MRO, you should just refer to `A` directly.

---

Long story short: use `A`, not `super`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The suggestion by Faibbus of using `__thisclass__` with `super` does seem to work, actually.

Comment: @PProteus: That's `B`. If you wanted to assign to `B.val_a`, you should assign to `B.val_a` directly, rather than taking a convoluted detour through `super`. It sounds like you wanted to assign to `A.val_a`, though.

Comment: You're right, thanks—I didn't catch that. I think I will just use A.val_a.

Comment: The value in setting `A`'s static attributes through `b` is that then I have a consistent interface; I can just use `b.whatever` for everything.

Answer (score 1):

Reference `A.val_a` directly. `val_a` in this case is a "static" variable, not an "attribute" of an object instance.

The `super` call tries to get the object of self instance, and thus access to attribute `super(B, self).val_a` will fail.

```
class A(object):
    val_a = 1

class B(A):
    val_b = 2

    def set_a(self, val):
        A.val_a = val 

b = B()
b.set_a(3)

print b.val_a
```

Comment: One of the main reasons for using `super()` is to avoid hardcoding [base] class name(s) into the code of subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with `super()`, but you can search through base classes of the subclass and do it that way.

Here's what I mean:

```
class Other(object):
    val_a = 42

class A(Other):
    val_x = 1

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}(val_a={})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.val_a)

class B(A):
    val_b = 2

    def set_a(self, val):
        for cls in self.__class__.__mro__[1:]:
            try:
                object.__getattribute__(cls, 'val_a')
            except AttributeError:
                continue
            print('Updating class: {}'.format(cls.__name__))
            cls.val_a = val
            break
        else:
            raise RuntimeError("Can't find a base class with attribute 'val_a'")

b = B()
print(b)  # -> B(val_a=1)                     # B(val_a=42)
print('Other.val_a: {}'.format(Other.val_a))  # Other.val_a: 42
print('A.val_a: {}'.format(A.val_a))          # A.val_a: 42
print('B.val_a: {}'.format(B.val_a))          # B.val_a: 42
print('')
b.set_a(3)                                    # Updating class: Other
print('')
print(b)                                      # B(val_a=3)
print('Other.val_a: {}'.format(Other.val_a))  # Other.val_a: 3
print('A.val_a: {}'.format(A.val_a))          # A.val_a: 3
print('B.val_a: {}'.format(B.val_a))          # B.val_a: 3
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a pretty neat solution. Perhaps more complicated than I need.

Comment: If you know there's only a single base class, you could hardcode things and just unconditionally use `self.__class__.__mro__[1].val_a = val`.

Comment: `hasattr(cls, 'val_a')` doesn't care about whether the attribute is actually defined in class `cls`; it'll pick up inherited attributes. The bug isn't visible here only because `val_a` is defined in the next class in the MRO.

Comment: @user2357112: Good catch...think I've fixed that in revised answer.

Comment: It kind of works better now, but not for good reasons, and probably not for the reasons you're thinking. `cls.__getattribute__` is the `__getattribute__` method used for *instances* of `cls`, not for `cls` itself. It just happens that this is usually `object.__getattribute__`, which doesn't know how to search `cls`'s MRO. If another `__getattribute__` method gets involved, things break.

Comment: The usual way to check if a class attribute is defined in a particular class is to look for it in the class's `__dict__` (or `vars`, if you prefer the function).

Comment: OK, so in your opinion do you think it would be acceptable to explicitly use `object.__getattribute__(cls, 'val_a')` instead (rather than checking for a `__dict__`, and if there is one, also checking its contents)?

Comment: Probably fine. It's not how I'd write it, and it could get a little weird with attribute names that coincide with metaclass attributes, but for normal attributes, it should work.

Comment: Thanks again. Feel free to [edit] and improved my answer or add your own.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code you are trying to make the change for the instance. Then, the function `set_a` needs to be as below.

```
class B(A):
    val_b = 2

    def set_a(self, val):
        self.val_a = val
```

But if you need the change to be applicable for the class level, you can use a class method and you can't use `super()`

```
class B(A):
    val_b = 2

    @classmethod
    def set_a_class(cls, val):
        cls.val_a = val

B.set_a_class(5)
print B.val_a

b = B()
print b.val_a
```

will return

> 5
>
> 5

Comment: No, sorry. That would only set the value of val_a for the particular instance. I want to set it for the class, A.

Comment: But according to you code the function is not a class method then it is only applicable for the particular instance. If you want to set the variable for the class `set_a` needs to be a class method.

Comment: It is an answer to your question saying `Can you set static class attributes using super()` otherwise can you please edit your question to make it more clear if you want the method to set the variable for the class.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have edited the title and question to make the intent more clear.

Answer (score 0):

See [Static variable inheritance in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475488/static-variable-inheritance-in-python)

```
class A(object):
    val_a = 1


class B(A):
    val_b = 2
    def set_a(self, val):
        type(self).val_a = val


b1 = B()
b1.set_a(3)
b2 = B()
b2.set_a(4)
print type(b1).val_a
print type(b2).val_a
print A.val_a
print B.val_a
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, just as with Faibbus' suggestion, this only changes the attribute for class B, not A. type(self) is not different from using self.__class__ as far as I can tell.

Comment: 1. type(self) is not different from using self.__class__  but looks better.

Comment: 2.. It depends upon the application. Assume that you do not want to mess with class A namespace and furthermore set_a method is defined in class A. In that case you may use this solution.